# winpy32 throws -2146826246 when accessing a specific cell using WorkSheet.Range('A1').value

Tags: excel, winapi, com, pywin32, pywin

I have a script that is reading a complex model in excel, using `pywin32`. In the first part of the script, model inputs are found from the *input worksheet* within the workbook through `InputWorkSheet.Range('A1').value`, and these return the appropriate cell values.

The model then runs, inside the excel workbook, and again I'm using `pywin32` to access the *model outputs*, albeit in a different worksheet, using the same function `OutputWorkSheet.Range('A1').value`.

The output cells are numerical datatypes, and when changing inputs using the excel app, the values on the outputs are a numerical datatype and output as normal. However, when accessing the output cell using the `pywin32` library, the cell always returns -2146826246, indicating a CVErr.

I've also tried other methods of accessing the cell value, such as using `worksheet.Cells(1,1).value`, with the same -2146826246 error code being thrown.

I'm trying to identify the source of the error, and the only resource found so far talks about it in the context of .NET: [link](https://xldennis.wordpress.com/2006/11/22/dealing-with-cverr-values-in-net-%E2%80%93-part-i-the-problem/).

Code, although not the full implementation:

```
import win32com.client 


example_file_location = "path/to/file.xlsx"

process_File = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application",pythoncom.CoInitialize()) 

process_File.Visible = 0


workBook = process_File.Workbooks.open(example_file_location) 
inputWorkSheet = workBook.Worksheets('Inputs')
outputWorkSheet = workBook.Worksheets('Outputs')
...
#code to give inputs
...

x = outputWorkSheet.Range('A1').value
```

Comment: `-2146826246` is the decimal representation of an [`HRESULT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/0642cb2f-2075-4469-918c-4441e69c548a) value. It encodes several pieces of information that are easier to see in hexadecimal display: `0x800A07FA`. It is an error (MSB set), the facility (`0xA`) is `FACILITY_CONTROL`, and the error code `0x7FA` (`2042` in decimal). With the `HRESULT` decomposed, you have far better information to inform further analysis.